# CakePHP - How to link to to a file that I created and doesn't come with the package

Tags: php, file, cakephp, directory

I am trying to make changes on a CakePHP cms site. I found "main_menu.cpt" file where is the main menu located. Following the existing menus I added my own:

```
<li>
  <a href="<?=$html->url('/'.$lang.'/orders');?>"<?=($page=='orders')?'class="active" ':''?>>
     <?__('orders')?>
  </a>
</li>
```

which is pointing to file orders.php but when I click on the link I get this message:

```
Not Found    
Error: The requested address '/en/orders' was not found on this server.
```

Where I must upload the file orders.php?
I know it sounds stupid, but this cms is totally new for me and even the directory structure doesn't help me :) Hope you will do it !

Thanks in advance

edit ################

```
<?php    
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'dpages', 'action' => 'home', 'lang'=>'bg'));
Router::connect('/:lang/', array('controller' => 'dpages', 'action' => 'home'), array( 'lang' => 'bg|en'));
Router::connect('/:lang/pages/:action/*', array('controller' => 'dpages'), array( 'lang' => 'bg|en'));
Router::connect('/:lang/:controller/:action/*', array('action' => 'index'), array( 'lang' => 'bg|en'));
Router::connect('/pages/:action/*', array('controller' => 'dpages'));
Router::connect('/dpages/*', array('controller' => 'dpages', 'action' => 'view'));
Router::connect('/admin', array('admin'=>1, 'controller' => 'dpages', 'action' => 'home'));
Router::connect('/tests', array('controller' => 'tests', 'action' => 'index'));
```

?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CakePHP is a framework.

You may need an OrdersController that has a view file for each method.
Check to see how the other pages are build (what files you have in the `Controllers` folder).

If you just want to add a content page, for orders, you can put it inside the `View/Pages` folder, and call it orders.ctp. 
You can access it on `site.com/pages/orders`

Add the following line in `Config/routes.php` (among the other `Router::connect` lines)

```
Router::connect('/:lang/orders', array('controller' => 'dpages', 'action' => 'orders'), array( 'lang' => 'bg|en'));
```

Go to `Controller/DPagesController.php` and add:

```
public function orders() {
    // can be blank for now
}
```

Go to `views/dpages` folder and create `orders.ctp` and put the static form in there.

Then try the link again.

Comment: thank you cornelb for helping me. My own page consists a static order form. I placed it in views/dpages folder but still get this error.. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: can you paste the content of your `Config/routes.php` file?

Comment: I followed the instructions, but still can not see my page, but the same Not fount message.. What I am doing wrong? Am I missing something?

Comment: can you go to `Config/core.php` and enable debug? Set `Configure::write('debug', 2);` Then you will get a more clear error message, like "Missing controller". That might be more helpful, to figure out what's wrong

Comment: cornelb, I was playing with urls and with this pages/orders have succeeded ! But really thank you for the time mate ! I accept your answer ! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

CakePHP is not designed for you to add additional php files like that, nor should it be.  Therefore I highly recommend that you rewrite whatever you have in your orders.php file to be use the CakePHP framework.

However, you can add orders.php into your app/Vendor folder, then include it in a controller's action (example:  `include_once(APP . 'Vendor/orders.php');` ).  Then, you should be able to access it via http://yourwebsite.com/controller/action where controller is the name of the controller you chose to put the include in, and action is the name of the action you chose to put the include in.

Comment: thank you Kai, but I am not sure how to use your answer.. have no experience with fameworks..